# How to delete a paragraph as quickly as possible

Tags: linux, vim

I want to delete the following codes in my config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx;
    location / {
        try_files xx;
    }
}
```

I know I can use <kbd>7</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, but this is not handy enough- if the section is too long, counting the rows would be inconvenient.

Is there a better way to do this?

Sometimes, I have to delete a whole function, any ideas for that?

Comment: For your second question- how to delete an entire C-style function- see [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723169/selecting-entire-function-definition-in-vim/11723259#11723259).

Answer (score 14):

As in common in Vim, there are a bunch of ways!

Note that the first two solutions depend on an absence of blank lines within the block.

- If your cursor is on the `server` line, try <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>. It will delete everything to the next block.
- Within the entry itself, <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> will delete the 'paragraph'.
- You can delete a curly brack block with <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>. (If you like this syntax, I recommend Tim Pope's fantastic [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), which adds more features with a similar feel).
- You could also try using regular expressions to delete until the next far left-indented closing curly brace: <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> move to the next/previous first-column curly brace (equivalent to using `/` and `?` with that regex I mentioned above. Combine with the <kbd>d</kbd> motion, and you acheive the same effect.
- If you're below a block, you can also make use of the handy 'offset' feature of a Vim search. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>?</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>{</kbd><kbd>?</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> will delete backwards to one line before the first occurrence of a first-column opening curly brace. This command's a bit tricky to type. Maybe you could make a `<leader>` shortcut out of it.

Note that much of this answer is taken from [previous answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11723259/815632) on a similar topic.

Comment: dupe answer? ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723169/selecting-entire-function-definition-in-vim/11723259#11723259

Comment: @Conner, I made note of that in the last line of my answer. And it's pretty much the same, but I did tweak it slightly to apply more to this question.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that. I was just teasing though - doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 6):

If there is a blank line immediately after these lines, Vim will identify it as a paragraph, so you can simply use `d}` to delete it (assuming the cursor is on the first line).

Answer (score 2):

Try using visual mode with %.

For example, say your cursor is at the beginning of the "server" line.

Press v to go into visual mode. Press % to highlight to the end of the block. Press d to delete it.

Comment: @user1503012, I'm not sure what you mean there, but as suggested by @pb2q, the shortest way you can do this spanning multiple lines (with blanks in-between) is using `d%`.

Answer (score 2):

As David said their are many ways. Here are a few that I like:

1. `Vf{%d` This assumes you are on the line w/ `server` and you do a visual line selection, find the `{` and then find the matching `}` via the `%` command.
2. `set relativenumber` or `set rnu` for short. This turns on line numbering relative to your cursor. So you do not have to count the lines just look and `7dd` away to deleting your block.
3. Use `VaB` to visually select a block i.e. `{` to `}`, line-wise. While still in visual mode continue doing `aB` until the proper block is selected then execute `d`. This means you can select a block from inside the block instead of at the start or end.
4. `d}` will delete a paragraph. This works in your current scenario because there is no blank line inside the block. If there is one then all bets are off. Although you can continue pressing `.` until the block is properly deleted.
5. If inside a block you can jump to the current block via `[{` then continue executing `[{` until you are at the correct block then `V%d` or `d%dd` to delete the block

Using the techniques above you can delete a function as well, but you can also use the `[M` and friends (`[m`, `]m`, `]M`) to jump to the start and endings of methods but they commonly work for functions as well.

For more information

```
:h %
:h 'rnu'
:h aB
:h }
:h .
:h [{
:h [m
```

Answer (score 1):

Given matching parens, or braces, you can use `%` with `d` to delete, spanning lines.

So, assuming that you're on the `server {` line, you can do `d%`. This is generally useful for all code blocks, e.g. function blocks, loop blocks, try blocks.

Similarly, `dip` works, but `d}` is shorter. However, both will only delete to the next empty line.