# Selecting (and deleting) entire function with definition (INCLUDING whitespace) in Vim

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, editor

I recently switched to using Vim (with VSCode) as my editor.

I'm trying to delete a function with it's definition in JavaScript. I looked on google and here on StackOverflow and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723169/selecting-entire-function-definition-in-vim). Unfortunately the answers for this question only work for functions without white space.

Here is how my function looks:

```
const useBattery = () => {
  const [battery, setBattery] = useState({ level: 0, charging: false });
  const handleChange = ({ target: { level, charging } }) => setBattery({ level, charging });

  useEffect(() => {
    let battery;
    navigator.getBattery().then(bat => {
      battery = bat;
      battery.addEventListener("levelchange", handleChange);
      battery.addEventListener("chargingchange", handleChange);
      handleChange({ target: battery });
    });
    return () => {
      battery.removeEventListener("levelchange", handleChange);
      battery.removeEventListener("chargingchange", handleChange);
    };
  }, []);
  return battery;
};
```

I tried several approaches, the best one was `da{` when my cursor is within the function. This motion will delete the function body, but not the definition.

Is there any way to delete the function and the definition in one motion using Vim, if there is white space in the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting entire function definition in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723169/selecting-entire-function-definition-in-vim)

Comment: VS-Code aside. Vim does not know what a function is. It just operates on text. So `da}` is pretty good (depending on cursor position a count might be needed). Also the answer of Jeremy is good. I doubt that you can get any closer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From inside the function, as you say `da{` deletes only the braces and its content, without the preceding declaration or the following semicolon. However... if we switch to linewise...?

There is a semi-hidden section a bit under `:help exclusive-linewise` with bold heading but no tag to jump to: "FORCING A MOTION TO BE LINEWISE, CHARACTERWISE OR BLOCKWISE", saying that we can switch to a non-default selection by using <kbd>v</kbd> (characterwise), <kbd>V</kbd> (linewise) or <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> (blockwise) immediately after the operator. So...

```
dVa{
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the post you linked to, `d]]` when the cursor is placed at the beginning of the function definition will delete the whole function.