# Select ruby method definitions in vim

Tags: ruby, vim

In languages with braces `{ ... }` around a function or method, it is easy to select the inner body definition of a method (see [Selecting entire function definition in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723169/selecting-entire-function-definition-in-vim)):

You can select the inner body with `vi{` or including the curly braces with `va}`.

However in Ruby, you don't have these. Methods are written with the `def ... end` syntax with optional round brackets:

```
def foo(bar)
  puts "foo: #{bar}"
end

def bar
  puts "bar"
end
```

Is there a way, to only select the inner body `puts "foo"` of a method in Ruby? How about the whole method definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in Ruby ftplugin adds, among other things, [a bunch of custom pseudo-text objects](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/doc/ft-ruby-plugin.txt#L58), so you can do `vim` or `vam`.

While the feature is documented in the project itself, it appears to not be *in Vim itself*, though, so you should probably ask the maintainers to improve that aspect of their project.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the text objects, exactly what I was looking for!